# Atlassian Jira was loaded in Chinese

Tags: jira

Our company uses Atlassian Jira. I've just tried to log in from the Internet, which was successful, but the page is loaded in Chinese:

[image]

Is it because of some settings? Or is it some security issus I just encountered?

The domain was in the following format: *.atlassian.net

Thank you

Comment: It's Korean btw.

Comment: :D alright, still incomprehensible to me.